# ros_control and hardware interface

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using diff_drive control package from ros_control.I have two dynamixel motors.How to register the motor with the *hardware interface* of ros_control and how to publish the velocity commands to dynamixel motor from diff_drive_controller I am a newbie.So please explain me with the code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226658/ros_control-and-hardware-interface./) by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 243 on 2016-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you check the [ros_control wiki](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/wiki)? Though not an extensive wiki, it provides some basic information.

Also you can check Dave's [ros_control_boilerplate](https://github.com/davetcoleman/ros_control_boilerplate) as your starting template.

And for general information, you can watch [Adolfo's ROSCON 14 talk on ros_control](https://vimeo.com/107507546).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4